# await useFetch and then passing data to another react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple useFetch() react hook that makes an api call to fetch data, I then want to pass that data to a custom usePagination() hook that processes the data and returns some of it to display.

something like this

```
const [data] = useFetch(`http://localhost:whatever`);
const {postDisplay} = usePagination(data);
```

The problem is that data is undefined until it finishes fetching, and usePagination crashes.
and being that it is a hook you can't call conditionally.

(I guess I can make useFetch async and await it, but it doesn't feel like that's the solution here)

Is there any easy ways around this?

Comment: does useFetch return anything? did you console.log that data?

Comment: returns nothing initially, but after a few renders it returns the expected data

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the condition inside the `usePagination` hook itself. If it receives `undefined` as the argument, it should still call all the other hooks it could have (like `useMemo` or `useState`), but bail out of all of them. Eg.:

```
function usePagination(data) {
  const postDisplay = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) return null
    // business as usual here
  }, [data])

  return {postDisplay}
}
```

If your hook doesn't call any other hooks, you can just return early:

```
function usePagination(data) {
  if (!data) return {postDisplay: null}
  
  // business as usual here
  return {postDisplay}
}
```

And inside your component, you handle the case when `postDisplay` is `null` as well.

Comment: that is basically what I did for now, it's just very messy cause I have a few useEffects etc.. will accept if no better answers come in... and shouldn't there be an easier way??